# Can we store smtp.js token in clear text in our code?

Tags: javascript, email

I am creating my portfolio (in html, css and js) which has a "contact" page with a form.
I would have liked it to be possible, from this form, to send me an email. So I did some research and I found an api that seems to do what I want: [Smtp.js](https://smtpjs.com/).
This api asks us to create a token in order not to enter the login and the password of our mailbox.
My question is: can we store this token in clear text in our code without risk and if not what to do?

Comment: You can try it yourself. Create the token and call it from localhost. If the e-mail arrives, it's not a good idea to do it (as an attacker I can use a farm of localhosts). The solution is simple and available for decades - use server side e-mail sender, with appropriate security measures. Also protect your contact form against robots.